# Protractor: automated .sendKeys() converting my text to CAPS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Using Protractor, I have a test where I'd like to automate changing the title of an item to "My New SPL". Everything works fine but for some reason it converts my text to all caps during the automated test. I can input lower case text fine manually. Has anyone else experienced this?

```
$('[ng-model="titleInput"]').clear().sendKeys("My New SPL");

expect(element.getText()...).toBe("My New SPL")

err: expected "My New SPL", instead got "MY NEW SPL"
```

also tried with no dice:

```
var myNewSPLString = String.fromCharCode(77, 121, 32, 78, 101, 119, 32, 83, 80, 76);
$('[ng-model="titleInput"]').clear().sendKeys(myNewSPLString);
```

Comment: Is your text only getting converted to caps on this element, or is `.sendKeys()` causing this behavior everywhere?

Comment: If you add browser and driver version that can help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Check the CSS on this element, CSS can convert lowercase to uppercase. If not changed be CSS,  it should be some key event bind to this element by developer, the event function change user input to uppercase.  I guess it also be uppercase when you input manually.